# Get image within PHP using specific name followed by $_GET variable

Tags: php, html, image, get

I wish to have a image taken from a folder and displayed in a PHP page.

I currently have this:

```
<img src="images/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($venue); ?>.jpg" alt="venueimage" height="150" width="250">
```

The above takes the `$_GET`  and assuming the $ is of value "1", displays the picture named '1.jpg'

I would like to make it so the image name could be 'venue1.jpg' with only the integer "1" being the get variable like the code above, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep doing what you are already doing. Hard code the `venue` portion of the image  name into your code:

```
<img src="images/venue<?php echo htmlspecialchars($venue); ?>.jpg" alt="venueimage" height="150" width="250">
```